# Strange MySQL command, what's it purpose?

Tags: mysql, sql

What does this command do in MySQL?

```
> /*!30020*/;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When parsing a dump file, mySQL can parse [conditional comments.](http://devzone.zend.com/1401/mysql-trick-with-comments/) This way, a database dump can contain commands that target a specific version of mySQL only. Popular uses for this include the `COLLATE` statement and the `SET NAMES` keyword.

The comment you show - if it contained an actual command in the end - would cause that command to be run only if mySQL's version is 3.0.0.2 or later.

Answer (score 2):

Its a comment tag, it does nothing.. Here's a reference: http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/blog/202